# Find $\int\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> Find $$\int\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x)\,dx$$

My Attempt:

$$\int\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x)\,dx = \frac18 \int ((1-\cos(2x)-\cos^2(2x)+\cos^3(2x))\, dx$$

How to proceed from here?

Comment: multiple online integral calculators give different answers so I don't know which one to believe in

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: try half-angle identities, but I have trouble with getting the algebra right

Comment: Show what you obtained with half angles, then we will be able to nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Try this: $\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x) = \frac 18 (\sin 2x)^2 (1-\cos 2x )$.

Comment: Where does 1-cos(2x) come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin^4 x\cos^2 x=(\sin^2x)(\sin^2x\cos^2x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2x)(\sin x\cos x)^2=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2x)(\frac{1}{2}\sin2x)^2$

$\hspace{1.25 in}=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2x)\frac{1}{4}\sin^22x=\frac{1}{8}(\sin^22x-\sin^22x\cos2x)$,

$\displaystyle\int\sin^4x\cos^2x=\frac{1}{8}\left(\int\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos4x)dx-\int\sin^22x\cos2xdx\right)$.

$\hspace{1.2 in}$(In the second integral, you can let $u=\sin2x, du=2\cos2xdx$.)

Comment: The final anwser is $x/16-sin(4x)/64-sin^3(2x)/24$? If not, why?

Comment: I think you just need to change the 24 to 48, since you have $\frac{1}{8}(\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2})$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin(x)^4 \cos(x)^2 = \sin(x)^4 (1-\sin(x)^2) = \sin(x)^4 - \sin(x)^6.$$

Now use the power reduction formulae:

$$\sin(x)^2 = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2} \\
\cos(x)^2 = \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$

Doing so several times you will get something of the form $a + b \cos(2x) + c \cos(4x) + d \cos(6x)$, which is now easy to integrate.

If you're curious about the derivation, the first one from the second because $\sin(x)^2 = 1-\cos(x)^2$. The second one comes because

$$\cos(2x)=\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2=\cos(x)^2-(1-\cos(x)^2)=2\cos(x)^2-1$$

and then you solve for $\cos(x)^2$.

Comment: I need help integrating $sin^4(x)-sin^6(x)$. I'm lost on the algebra.

Comment: $\sin(x)^4$ is $(\sin(x)^2)^2$. Apply the formula to each of these factors. Now you have something involving $\cos(2x)^2$. Apply the other formula to that, and the overall result will be of the form $a + b \cos(2x) + c \cos(4x)$. Now do a similar, slightly more complicated thing for $\sin(x)^6$.

Comment: To integrate those, I first used the power reductions and with those I tried factoring out the two of the denominator of the power reduction formula and using the identity -cos(2x) = -1+sin^2(x). That got me to the the integral of sin^4(x) is "sin^9(x)/9". I know sin(x) to the ninth power is definitely wrong. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Huh? None of what you just said made any sense. You should get $\sin(x)^4 = \left ( \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2} \right )^2 = \frac{1-2 \cos(2x) + \cos(2x)^2}{4}$. Now use the formula again on the third term.

Comment: I just dropped a dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\sin(x)^4\cos(x)^2=\frac{1}{32}(-\cos(2x)-2\cos(4x)+\cos(6x)+2)$$

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is wrong and that there is a term with angular frequency 6.

Comment: can you post a counter example?

Comment: yes sorry it was a typo